# React-native Android emulator - POST fails with TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to hit an API which is on VPN. I made sure my laptop is connected to VPN - I can make the POST login request successfully from Chrome REST Client. Also - my iOS counterpart app runs fine on iOS simulator, running the same fetch() code, etc.

react-native version I'm on:

react-native-cli: 0.2.0

react-native: 0.22.2

My code in login class is:

```
var LOGIN_URL = 'http://<mydomain>/portal/api/v1.0/user/authenticate/';

class DroidLogin extends Component {
  ...
  onLoginPressed() {
    this._authenticate();
  }


  _authenticate() {

    fetch(LOGIN_URL + "<username>", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({password:<password>})
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log("Response data token is: " + responseData.token);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('We have an error logging in...');
      console.warn(error);
    })
    .done();
  }

  ...
}
```

The errors I see in Chrome debugger:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
  at xhr.onload (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:14679:8)
  at XMLHttpRequest._sendLoad (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:57127:1)
  at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:57117:6)
  at XMLHttpRequest._didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:57012:6)
  at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:56950:105
  at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:51351:23)
  at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:51547:23)
  at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:51451:8
  at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:51405:1)
  at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:51450:1)
```

What do I need to change when running on Android emulator? Thank you!

Comment: Can you make the request or get to one of those URLs from a browser on you android simulator?  Networking on the android simulator is a bit strange and it basically acts like it's own machine.

Comment: I get net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. I'm thinking if the problem stems from the fact that react native development server for android is under 10.0.2.2 or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The first time I got this error I was able to solve it by running this command

```sh
adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
```

And now the request is going through just fine, but it still gives me this error on the `.catch()`

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```